# Creating ARM node pool on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to create an ARM based node pool, on GKE cluster and I'm getting an error which isn't too informative:

`Empty name and project for ARM, as current version is not supported.`

Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was wrong cluster version.
ARM node pools on GKE requires Kubernetes cluster version of 1.24 or higher.